# Android - Change Hamburger/Back icons color programmatically during runtime

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I'm trying to change the style attribute "colorControlNormal" of my app programmatically and during runtime, but I didn't have any results.

This property is the color that will tint the hamburger & back icons of the new Toolbar viewGroup. Beside, I'm using the v7 compatibility library.

I heard that we cannot change app theme during runtime, but I'm looking for an answer, even if it's not so clean way.

Edit:

I just figured that gmail is doing what i want, when you click on the search icon, the white hamburger icon turn into grey back.

Waiting for more.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can change theme at runtime only if you are doing it before `setContentView()`

Comment: you could change the color only if you're using a custom view for your action bar.

Comment: @Bacs:i didn't tried anything from now, i dont know what to try :/

Comment: @pdegand59 i want something else, something to do it un m'y fragments, after the setcontentview ...

Comment: Then you have to do a custom view on the actionbar or reload the activity with the new theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent one day, played with different implementation. So my opinion, the best way todo that it copy paste DrawerArrowDrawable from AppCompat v7 library.

https://gist.github.com/IstiN/5d542355935fd7f0f357 - take a look on the code with some optimization

than you can use it in your main activity with code below

```
        DrawerArrowDrawable drawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(this, this);
        ImageView menuButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        menuButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer)).openDrawer(Gravity.START);
            }
        });
```

when you start new fragment, you need to create one more view on the same place and add second code to your fragment

```
    private DrawerArrowDrawable mArrowDrawable;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mArrowDrawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(getActivity(), getActivity());
        ImageView topButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        topButton.setImageDrawable(mArrowDrawable);
        topButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                closeSearch();
            }
        });

        //run animation from hamburger to arrow
        animate(0, 1, null);
        ....

    private void animate(int startValue, int endvalue, Animator.AnimatorListener listener) {
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startValue, endvalue);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                mArrowDrawable.setProgress(slideOffset);
            }
        });
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(300);
        if (listener != null) {
            anim.addListener(listener);
        }
        anim.start();
    }
```

to make animation from arrow to hamburger handle back button and execute code

```
animate(1, 0, null);
```

you also need to wait in your fragment while animation will not finish, but it another questions.

If you have any questions ask in comments.